# Populate AuthContext in gRPC C# from JWT Authentication

Tags: c#, jwt, interceptor, grpc

Basically what I want to do:

1. Client-Side (get a token, attach is as a metadata-token and send it to the different services) -- **DONE**
2. Server-side (get the token, verify issuer, date and audience) -- **DONE**
3. Server-side (After verifying the token, I would like to populate the fields of the AuthContext, so that  I can use them in the my GrpcServices) -- **Need help here**

So Far I manage to return a ClaimsPrinciple from my tokenChallenger.GetClaimsPrincipal(token) method, however I am unsure how to populate the AuthContext.

I was reading the [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/server_side_auth.md) , and I basically need an interceptor on the server side.

Here is my code so far

```
public class AuthInterceptor: Interceptor
{
    private readonly JwtTokenChallenger _tokenChallenger;
    public AuthInterceptor(JwtTokenChallenger tokenChallenger)
    {
        _tokenChallenger = tokenChallenger;
    }


    public override Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, ServerCallContext context,
        UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {


        Task<TResponse> response;

        var isThisProtectedMethodAttribute = IsThisProtectedMethod(continuation.Target.GetType(), context);

        if (isThisProtectedMethodAttribute == null) //only protected methods have attributes.
        {
            response = continuation(request, context);
            return response;
        }
        //jwt token validation;
        //populate auth context with claims principle?
        var token = context.RequestHeaders.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Key == "authorization").Value.Split(" ").Last();
        if (token == null)
        {
            context.Status = new Status(StatusCode.Unauthenticated, "Invalid token");
            return default(Task<TResponse>);
        }

        if (ValidateToken(token))
        {
            PopulateAuthContext(token, context);
            return continuation(request, context);
        }
        context.Status = new Status(StatusCode.Unauthenticated, "Invalid token");
        return default(Task<TResponse>);

        //test


    }

    private ProtectedMethod IsThisProtectedMethod(Type t, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        List<ProtectedMethod> returnAttributes = new List<ProtectedMethod>();

        Attribute[] attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(t);
        foreach (Attribute attr in attrs)
        {
            if (attr is ProtectedMethod a && (a.ProtectedResourceAcceessMethodName == context.Method.Split("/").Last()))
            {
                return a;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private bool ValidateToken(String tokenToValidate)
    {
        return _tokenChallenger.isValidToken(tokenToValidate); 
    }

    private void PopulateAuthContext(String token, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        //help needed?
    }
}
```

Client-side I use Java (Android), Server-side I use C#

Edit: token has 2 things that I want, nameidentifier and roles

Answer (score 3):

The gRPC C# API doesn't allow you to populate AuthContext, the AuthContext can only be populated by gRPC internally (if you use TLS certificate-based authentication).
You basically have two options here:

1. you can populate the request metadata of the request with additional entries you need to pass to the actual method handlers (server-side interceptor can modify the metadata). Note: if you decide to populate the metadata, you need to be very careful about making sure that a malicious client can't send corresponding metadata entries along with her request and thus fake that she's been authenticated. You can do that e.g. by adding one more interceptor that strips all the sensitive headers from all incoming requests.
2. your interceptor can set the auth-related values into an execution context that's compatible with async/await. That way, the values will be accessible from the async methods that implement the server-side behavior. See e.g. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html for more info on C# contexts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third option as well, populate a new derived class of the ServerCallContext, with a new AuthContext populated with your claims. You can cache the transformation from the token